# Overriding an import made in a dependency when using Vite

Tags: dependencies, vite, package.json

I'm using Vite as the build tool for my application. In one of my dependencies, there's an `import from "three"` command. The problem is, I need it to use my own fork of three.js instead of the official library. I've read about the `overrides` property of package.json, but it didn't work. I also tried using Vite's (rollup's) `resolve.alias` property and that didn't work as well, but I'm not sure I've set it up correctly (Vite's documentation is minimal on that aspect).

Vite complains: `Could not resolve "three"`

Any help will be much appreciated.